# Android: how to transform lat & lon in a given angle?

Tags: android, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have lat & lon that need to plot into floor map image.
The problem is the floor map image's angle is not proportionate with the real world map. Anybody knows how to transform real lat & lon values in a given angle?

**UPDATES1**
I have previous posted question which has relation with this post. Please take a look.
[plot real world coor to still image map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395647/android-how-to-plot-a-real-world-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-to-still-im)

Comment: What you are trying to do is called a projection.

Answer (score 0):

Latitude, Longitude refers to a single point on earth's surface. It does not have an angle.

If you are talking about the Location class however, you can get it's bearing from North, using

```
if(location.hasBearing())
 location.getBearing()
```

If you are talking about a pair of lat, lon values, you can calculate the bearing using the `bearingTo()` api

Comment: I don't sure if Angle is the correct term but to explain it, would you take a look the added link above. I am saying that if you see the top view of the real worl map and my floor map, the position(angle) of the building is not the same.