# How to mark a given Latitude and Longtitude into still image map

Tags: android, android-imageview

@Dan S, gave the below statement in this post -> [display a still image map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062115/android-how-to-display-a-map-still-image-file-with-a-moving-current-location)

> Then using a second ImageView (for the indicator) draw it on top and
>   move it to the correct place on the screen and make sure the
>   background in this View is transparent as well as the background of
>   your indicator

How can I create the second ImageView for my indicator? It should be transparent imageview as well as the indicator image.

**UPDATE:**
**I am asking here on how to overlap my image map ImageView and transparent indicator ImageView in order to mark the current location.**

Comment: My apology, i mean is on how to overlap the second ImageView to mark the current location against to image map by the given coordinates not on how to create the ImageView. I have my convert class from real life coordinates to pixel. The problem is on how to overlap the two ImageView. Let me to update my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) is transparent by default.
Your indicator image resource should have a transparent background (e.g. transparent .PNG image).

Just set the ImageView's imageResource or backgroundResource to the PNG file.

So your code for creating your ImageView will be something like this:

```
ImageView myImageView = new ImageView(context);
myImageView.setBackgroundColor(0x0); // not needed - it's the default
myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.indicator_icon);
```

but again, this's the default and you still have to make sure your image's background is transparent otherwise the ImageView's background won't matter.

**UPDATE**: following @eros update of the question, here's an updated answer:
There are two options, i can think of, to achieve positioning of one imageview on top of the other:

1. use the LayoutParams and set the margins to the position the indicator imageview
2. draw the indicator imageview on top of the map bmp's canvas

personally i like the first option better because future changes won't force you to repaint the indicator.

here's a class demonstrating option (1):

```
public class MyMapView extends RelativeLayout {
    private ImageView mBackImageView;
    private ImageView mIndicatorImageView;

    public MyMapView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mBackImageView = new ImageView(context);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        mBackImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
        mBackImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        addView(mBackImageView, params);

        mIndicatorImageView = new ImageView(context);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams indParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mIndicatorImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
        addView(mIndicatorImageView, indParams);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        centerIndicatorPosition();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        centerIndicatorPosition();
    }

    // @eros: this's the part you want. this method just centers the indicator view
    // but if you have the relative position like you say, use it for the margins
    private void centerIndicatorPosition() {
        int xPos = (getMeasuredWidth() - mIndicatorImageView.getMeasuredWidth()) / 2;
        int yPos = (getMeasuredHeight() - mIndicatorImageView.getMeasuredHeight()) / 2;
        ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)mIndicatorImageView.getLayoutParams())
            .setMargins(xPos, yPos, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I update my post to add more information. I am asking for on how to overlap two imageview to mark my current location.

Comment: May I ask the settings of extended RelativeLayout (e.g. Layout Parameters)?

Comment: @eros - If you're asking about the LayoutParams you should use for the MyMapView class, then it depends on the overall layout you need. You can add it to another ViewGroup and use:
    new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)

Comment: Cool~ got it. Let me to state here that my ultimate goal are to (1) mark the current (2) mark the destination (3) support the 1&2 while zooming in/out. I will post it as another question, would you check it out also...